# Need to input value for argparse. but it is not working

Tags: python, argparse, command-line-tool

i am trying to use python argparse in the following code. I want the user to enter the text as below.
-x 8 -l 9 -b 20

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Sample coding with arguments')
parser.add_argument('-x', '--height', help='Height of the box')
parser.add_argument('-l', '--length', type=int, help='Length of the box')
parser.add_argument('-b', '--breadth', type=int, help='Breadth of the box')
args = parser.parse_args([input("enter text: ")])
print (args)
```

the user should only enter these data when the system ask to enter.
the following code work if i enter a value for only 1 argument. But is not working if i use more than 1.
With two arguments it is showing this result

enter text: -x 9 -l 7

Namespace(height=' 9 -l 7', length=None, breadth=None)

Both value was assigned to height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a python script with arguments from the command line, say:

```
test.py -x 9 -l 7
```

The interpreter has a `sys.argv` of

```
sys.argv == ["test.py", "-x", "9", "-l", "7"]
```

By default argparse is provided `sys.argv[1:]` or `["-x", "9", "-l", "7"]`

You provided `["-x 9 -l 7"]`

Instead you need to split the string:

```
parser.parse_args(input("enter text: ").split())
```